# Some questions about $\gcd(n,m)$ and $\phi(n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pattern-recognition, totient-function

I was messing around in Excel at the end of work today and made a table where the $(i,j)$ entry $a_{i,j}$, for $j \geq i$, is 1 exactly when $i$ and $j$ are coprime (see snapshot of a portion of the table below):

[image]

My questions are:

- Is there an explanation for the highlighted rectangular pattern that keeps popping up (albeit in different orientations)?
- What about the numbers where $a_{*j}$ is $0$ for "most" values of $j$.  They seem to be sandwiched between twin primes or at least right next to a prime.  Is there any significance there?
- Another question that popped out of this, are there infinitely many solutions for $\phi(n) = \phi(n+1)$?  I also calculated $\phi(n)$ directly at the top of my table and noticed that the pattern for solutions seemed somewhat erratic.  Is there a theorem related to this at all?

These questions are rather open ended and I apologize.  Just trying to see if there is any merit to my curiosity today.

Comment: Note that numbers $n$ such that $\phi(n)=\phi(n+1)$ are tabulated, with references to the literature, at http://oeis.org/A001274

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twin primes are always either side of a multiple of 6 (except for the first twin primes, 3 and 5).  Why is that?
I think the numbers with most blank space below them are multiples of 6.  Why would most numbers have a factor in common with any multiple of 6?
I don't know about your last question.  None the less, playing around with maths is (a) fun and (b) how a lot of maths gets discovered.

Comment: You are right, given three consecutive numbers $p_n, m, p_{n+1}$ (with $p_{n} > 5$) say, then one of them must be a multiple of $3$.  Clearly that means $m$ is.  Similarly one of $p_{n}$ and $m$ are divisible by $2$, thus $m = 6k$ for some integer $k$.  I want to accept your answer for giving that hint but I still want to somehow keep the answer open for discussion about the other two questions.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I don't know exactly how these work.  Thanks for the upvote anyway :)